# Give an error when a model is deleted in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to give back an error if a particular model is deleted in Rails 3.x+? If it's deleted via the web, an error code is given back. If it's deleted via console then a message is given with the reason it can't be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `before_destroy`. The link is [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). Returning false from this validation message prevents the destruction of the object.

Comment: I didn't know returning false prevents destruction, nice!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way that I usually delete something is...

from the view:

```
<%= link_to "Delete Post", @post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You're sure you want to DELETE the post '#{@post.title}'?" } %>
```

then in the post controller:

```
def destroy
  Post.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "Blog entry deleted!"
  redirect_to posts_path
end
```

So, the `method: :delete` just gets to the `destroy` route of the controller. Then you do what you want, right?

So instead of `.destroy` after you find the model, you could do:

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  flash[:notice] = "Blog entry can't be deleted..."
  puts "#{@post.name} can't be deleted because..." #this line is what shows up in the console
  redirect_to posts_path
end
```

Comment: This would just be from the web, but not also the console. Basically I want a way to specify on the model itself this can't be deleted.